# is not public in 'retrofit2.Retrofit' , cannot be accessed from outside

Tags: java, android, retrofit, retrofit2, okhttp

im new in retrofit and im using retrofit2 version 2.4.0 . there is my Api client code :

```
public class ApiClient {


public static final String BASE_URL = "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/";
public static Retrofit retrofit = null;

public static Retrofit getApiClient (){

    if (retrofit == null){


        retrofit = new Retrofit().Builder.baseUrl(BASE_URL).
                addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();

    }
    return retrofit;

}
```

}

this is my error : is not public in 'retrofit2.Retrofit' , cannot be accessed from outside

its showing me error on this part of the code : new Retrofit().Builder

Comment: Use `new Retrofit.Builder()` instead of `new Retrofit().Builder` it follows the Builder Pattern

Comment: funny mistake . thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to instantiate Retrofit like this

```
public class ApiClient {


 public static final String BASE_URL = "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/";
 public static Retrofit retrofit = null;

 public static Retrofit getApiClient() {

  if (retrofit == null) {


   retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                  .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                  .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                  .build();

  }
  return retrofit;

 }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem.

Use `Retrofit.Builder()` instead of `Retrofit().Builder()`.